# Redirect_to not able to redirect to root url Rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am new to Rails and I am unable to redirect to root URL after logout the user, I have checked many solutions but all have same approach redirect_to, When I have used redirect_to to redirect to root URL then it has added the same URL two times. Please see below code.

```
def user_logout
    redirect_to URI(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]).host
end
```

it works fine but added the root URL two times, like test.comtest.com

Comment: Why are you using Rails 2.3.18? Its ancient, you should start on Rails 4 instead and make sure you are following tutorials / materials written in the last few years.

Comment: It may be legacy project

Comment: Please update the question with `routes.rb` code.

Comment: Why can't you just use `root_path`?

Comment: @pavan 
map.login 'login/user_logout',
     :controller => 'login',
     :action    => 'user_logout'

Answer (score 2):

Normaly you should use `root_path` a routes helper method to get the root path as suggested in the comments.

If you want to parse an url you need to call the parse method of URI before you can ask the uri object for an attribute.

```
URI.parse("https://www.google.com/some/path").host
```

or

```
uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/some/path")
uri.host   # => "www.google.com"
uri.path   # => "/some/path"
uri.query  # => nil
uri.scheme # => "https"
uri.port   # => 443
```

Comment: Can you tell me why the root url comes twice .??

Comment: I have checked this code and same issue  and also used the same code in my controller URI(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]).host

Comment: Sorry, I tried to figure it out. But I can't. Which ruby version do you use? What happens, if you use the parse method?

Comment: I am using ruby-1.9.3-p551 Actually its old project and I can't upgrade it to new versions due to many conflicts

Comment: Did you try the root_path helper? This would be the best and easiest solution.